# How export a spreadsheet as XML?

Tags: google-sheets, formatting, export, xml

How can I export a simple spreadsheet, consisting of a single column of data, as `XML`?

Exporting as `CSV` is leading to [other](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54138568/262852) problems, so turning to `XML` as a workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- add this add-on to your spreadsheet - **[https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/export-sheet-data/bfdcopkbamihhchdnjghdknibmcnfplk?hl=en)**
- open your spreadsheet you want to export
- go to **Add-ons**
- select **Export Sheet Data**
- select format **XML** and other settings
- click on **<kbd>Export</kbd>** button
- click on the download button

[image]

Comment: Updated link to the Export Sheets Data Sheets Add-On:
https://workspace.google.com/marketplace/app/export_sheet_data/903838927001